# I wanted to assemble two files .But i had made a mistake on my nasm commands.Bootloader is not running properly.What to do?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader, disk

So i have two files namely boot.asm and data.asm.I ran some NASM commands to appends the two assembly files(512 bytes sectors) to create a 1024 bytes virtual hard disk.But after running on an emulator , i saw that the simple 'hello world ' string on my data.asm file is not appearing on the screen.

the boot.asm file is-

```
ORG 0
BITS 16
start:
cli ;disables interrupts

mov ax,0x7c0
mov ds,ax
mov es, ax
mov ax,0x00
mov ss,ax
sti ;enables interrupts

;setup registers to read from disk

mov bh,0x0200
mov ah, 0x02
mov al, 0x01
mov ch ,0x00
mov cl,0x02
mov dh,0x00
mov dl,0x80
int 0x13 ;reads disk

mov si,0x200
call print ;calls print function
jmp $

print:
mov bx,0 ;clears bx register

.loop
lodsb ;load byte at address si into al and increment si
cmp al,0 ;compare value in al to 0
je .done ;is al is 0 , end of string
call print_char ;prints charcatar in al
.done
ret ;return from print function

print_char:
mov ah,0eh ;move 0eh into ah
int 0x10 ;handles screen operations
ret
times 510 -($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

data.asm file is-

message: db 'hello world',0
times 512 -($-$$) db 0 ;fills rest of sector with zeros upto 510 bytes
dw 0xAA55
```

The commands i used were-

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
nasm -f bin data.asm -o data.bin

dd if=./boot.bin of=./os.bin
```

I ran this -

```
dd if=./data.bin conv=notrunc oflag=append of=os.bin
```

instead of

```
dd if=./data.bin conv=notrunc oflag=append of=./os.bin.
```

Then i ran-

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda os.bin.
```

So the string 'Hello world' defined in data.asm file is not running properly.

Comment: `of=os.bin` and `of=./os.bin` are equivalent.  But `of=os.bin.` creates a file with a `.` (dot) at the end of its name, which is the filename you're telling `qemu` to look for.  But that file was previously empty, not created by NASM, so you just copied `data.bin` to it, not merging.  If you ran `dd ...  of=os.bin`, nothing would create the input file you told QEMU to read.

Comment: Yes but if i try to redo my commands, it still doesn't work for correct one which is ./os.bin.

Comment: Update your question with the exact commands you did try, without trailing `.` if that wasn't in your real command.  (Probably a good idea to `rm *.bin *.bin.` first to make sure you don't have any old files that you're still appending to.   (`cat boot.bin data.bin > os.bin` is easier to use than `dd` but does the same thing in this case.)  Before anyone spends time looking at your asm, we need to make sure you built it right and started QEMU with the right disk image.  Also, you should be running QEMU with `-gdb tcp:12345` or something so you can attach with GDB and single-step.